# Watermark per Page Not Working

Tags: microsoft-word

I am attemptinhg to place a Watermark only on certain pages and I have followed the instruction to add new Section and unlink the section exactly as describe here:

office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-or-change-a-watermark-HA102809779.aspx

The problem is that the Watermark is still showing on all pages above the unlinked section break.

Could it be some other setting that I need to unselect or select?

Comment: Is "Different First Page" checked for your header options? It would be helpful to have the actual document. Can you link it?